# Solve a Timeout Error caused by slow email

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, web-services

**The Problem**

I have a web service that saves a record in the database and, sometimes send out notification emails to a group of users letting them know an event occurred.

I am getting ***infrequent*** time-out errors from the client.  Since the data are committed to the database, I think my problem is that sending the SMTP server sending the emails is taking longer than the timeout on the client.

**The Need**

What I am need to do is to send the email either in the background or add it to some sort of queue for sending later and return.

**Constraints**

- Our site runs .Net 2.0 and IIS 6
- I do not have admin rights to the server, although I do have file-system access to our web site.  While I may be able to convince our server admin to install a custom windows service for me, I would prefer to avoid this if possible.
- Our web server is old and slow and is shared with several other web sites.
- This problem occurred in an important online data entry system, where downtime and errors cause political issues.

**Ideas**

I've looked at several solutions, but need some direction as to which way would be best.

1. I could spawn a thread to send the emails, but I don't know if that
   would work, since the web service code would fall out of scope upon
   return.
2. I could add the task to some sort of queue, and periodically send queued emails.
3. increase the timeout on the client side and ignore the problem.

Under #2, I've looked at J[eff Atwood's use of the HttpRuntime.Cache to simulate a windows service](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/) but am very concerned with the warning

> You need to really be careful on the length of the task running.
> Every new Task is a new Worker Thread and there’s a limited number of
> those – as it “borrows” a thread from the managed thread pool.

An unresponsive web page is worse than the error I'm trying to solve.

What direction should I go?

**The Web Service Code**

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration = 0)]
        public static string SaveRecord(comRecord record, IList<QIData> qiItems)
        {
          using (WebDatabase db = new WebDatabase())
          {
               db.SaveRecord(record, qiItems, UserId, ComId);
                   if (qiItems.Count>0)
               {
                /*Then somehow invoke or queue the routine 
                  db.SendQINotice(record,UserId, (int)ComId));
                 */
               }
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting - there are several ways to do it, but since you are on a web site, I would add an entry to an e-mail queue in a database and have another task send out the e-mail.  Then you have the freedom to do some better error handling on the e-mail send if you need to without slowing down the web site.  For instance, you could add some "transient" error handling to such an application.  If you are interested in this approach, I can add to my response the "transient" error handler that I am using to retry on an exception to overcome some temporary error conditions.

Comment: The main issue is the SMTP server can be really slow, not SMTP errors.  The server is doing at least double duty (it's also running an SQL instance and running some automated tasks.  I did not set that up.)  A test record I created which sent nine notification emails took almost 2 minutes)

Comment: Hmm, in an ideal world, the SQL would be on a seperate computer and you could have another system offload the SMTP task, but we don't always get anywhere close to ideal.  Still, I think seperating the e-mail from the web service might help your e-mail situation and the web service.  The e-mail might still take awhile, but it won't hold up the web service.  I don't know if you have the ability to easily add a new service to do the e-mailing, but that would be my preference.

Comment: I agree with you about offloading the emails.  My issue is how to do so.  I don't have admin rights to the box, and our admins are always busy and I don't know if they would approve of me creating a Windows Service to run in the background to do the email.

Comment: Alright - do you have another server that has access to the DB on that server?  Could you offload it to another server maybe - one that you could put a service on?  Just trying to think of alternates - ones that you might have already thought of.  If you have thought of every other possible way - doing what Jeff Attwood decribes might not be all that bad.  With .net 2.0 and II6 it must be an older OS version so your other options are limited.

Comment: By policy, automated tasks have to run on servers.  I do not have admin privileges to any non-dev servers.  The same box that runs the SMTP server also runs some scheduled Python tasks.  I am not happy with running the task periodically on a SQL server, for fear of impeding performance.  I'm looking into doing Jeff Atwood's process on my test box.